# Elegant way to tidy data with two levels of header, preserving both headers in tall format

Tags: r, tidyr

An [online tutorial](http://garrettgman.github.io/tidying/) says this about tidyr's gather function:

> gather() collects a set of column names and places them into a single “key” column.

But, I want two key columns as I am being given data with two levels of header. A minimal working example is:

```
top_heads <- c(rep("Group1", 3), rep("Group2", 3))
bottom_heads <- c(rep(c("low", "medium", "high"),2))
values <-  matrix(rep(1:5, 6), ncol = 6)
table <- rbind(top_heads, bottom_heads, values)
print(table)
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]    
top_heads    "Group1" "Group1" "Group1" "Group2" "Group2" "Group2"
bottom_heads "low"    "medium" "high"   "low"    "medium" "high"  
              "1"      "1"      "1"      "1"      "1"      "1"     
              "2"      "2"      "2"      "2"      "2"      "2"     
              "3"      "3"      "3"      "3"      "3"      "3"     
              "4"      "4"      "4"      "4"      "4"      "4"     
              "5"      "5"      "5"      "5"      "5"      "5"
```

I would like to tidy this data, using gather or a similar function, keeping the heads and subheads each in their own column. So it would look like:

```
Group   Range Value
Group1  low    1
Group1  low    2
```

et cetera.

I could cat the headers, convert to data frame,convert values to numeric, run gather, then split the headers (now keys). Is there a better solution?

Comment: Try `library(tidyr); as.data.frame(t(table)) %>% gather(key, Value, -top_heads, -bottom_heads) %>% select(-key) %>% rename(Group = top_heads, Range = bottom_heads)`